# Haskell - How does a pattern match fail in a list comprehension?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, list-comprehension

I'm learning Haskell with Miran Lipovaca's "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!". In page 82 it says

> If a pattern match fails, the list comprehension will just move on to the next element, and the element that failed won’t be included in the resulting list.

Example:

```
ghci> let xs = [(1,3),(4,3),(2,4),(5,3),(5,6),(3,1)]
ghci> [a+b | (a, b) <- xs]
[4,7,6,8,11,4]
```

My question is how does a pattern match fail?
What does he mean by that? I really don't get it. It could be because of my weak english. I please you for an example because I think the book doesn't give any example for failing pattern match.

I thought about something like if the list contains a type that couldn't be processed by the list comprehension then it moves to the next element but if I change the list in this way:

```
let xs = [(1,3),(4,3),(2,4),(5,3),True,(5,6)]
```

Then it doesn't even compile because it "couldn't match expected type"...

Comment: Try `[a | (a, 3) <- xs]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. :) Now I know what is meant!

Comment: The pattern is indeed (a,b) just like in a function (\a b -> a+b) 1 2 --vs-- ((a,b) -> a+b) (1,2), (a b) in your example would fail. You could use a single variable a <- xs but you would have to split them with fst a snd a in the result clause or feed a 2-tuple to a function that takes one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a few cases of failing pattern matching in list comprehensions, demoed in GHCi:

```
Prelude> [ () | True <- [True, False,True] ]
[(),()]
Prelude> [ x | (x, True) <- [(1,True), (2,False), (3,True)] ]
[1,3]
Prelude> [ x+1 | Left x <- [Left 1, Right "Hello", Right "world", Left 2] ]
[2,3]
```

Note that some patterns can never fail, e.g. `x`, `(x,y)`, or `(x,(a,b),z)`. This is because they match types having only a constructor, which has to match being the only one.

In general, pattern matching involves multiple branches, e.g.

```
case someValue of
   Left x  -> ...
   Right y -> ...

foo Nothing = ...
foo (Just x) = ...
```

In these cases, if we forget to handle a constructor, we get a runtime error when that case occurs. (Turning on warnings helps in avoiding this!).

In list comprehensions generators `p <- ...`, instead, we can only specify one pattern. However, a special rule applies: failure of pattern matching is not an error, but is simply ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much for this example. I got it.

Answer (score 7):

That's *not* an example of pattern-match failure (the tuple pattern matches *always*). This would be an example:

```
Prelude> xs = [Just (1,3), Just (4,3), Nothing, Just (5,3), Nothing]
Prelude> [a+b | Just (a, b) <- xs]
[4,7,8]
```

Here, the pattern `Just (a, b)` matches only the elements `Just (1,3)`, `Just (4,3)` and `Just (5,3)`, but not the `Nothing`s, so these positions just don't turn up in the final list.